# Adding HttpHeaders to the Websocket.Client by Mariusz Kotas (Marfusios)

Tags: c#, websocket

I use the Websocket.Client library by Mariusz Kotas.
I'm trying to add custom HttpHeaders to the client and I don't know how to do it. I am trying the below method SetRequestHeader but NativeClient is null at run time.

```
using (var client = new WebsocketClient(url))
{
    client.NativeClient.Options.SetRequestHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate");
    client.NativeClient.Options.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
        Log.Information($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));

    client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg => Log.Information($"Message received: {msg}"));
    client.Start();

    Task.Run(() => client.Send("{ message }"));

    exitEvent.WaitOne();

}
```

Can someone advise how this can be done?

I can define the headers as below

```
var headers = new HttpRequestMessage().Headers;
headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate");
headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
```

but how to add them to the client?

Comment: https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client look at the documentation. Here on the startpage its described as "Advanced configuration" how to provide your own ClientWebSocket with its options and presumably also access to the headers.

Comment: Ok, there are indeed advanced options, but I still don't know how to add headers. Can I have a simple example please?

Comment: What problem do you have? The factory method is just a method returning a ClientWebSocket. In that method you can do whatever you need to do with the ClientWebSocket instance before returning it. So basically the same you where trying to do on client.NativeClient.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ralf for the hint, that was the point. Below I show how I modified the code to make it work as I wanted.

```
var factory = new Func<ClientWebSocket>(() =>
{
    var client = new ClientWebSocket { Options = { KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) } };
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8");
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    client.Options.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36");
    return client;
});
WebsocketClient client = new(uri, factory)
{
    ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    MessageEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
};
```